# Does two possible answers make a question too broad?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons

Someone posted this question earlier today:
[A Mathematical Proverb](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/20286/a-mathematical-proverb)

Both my answer and Cain's answer had basically the same explanation, but his was accepted, as it was the answer that the asker had in mind (as a more common proverb). The answer was accepted within about half an hour of the question being posted, so there wasn't much time for it to be closed for ***too broad*** if it would be. Afterward I was wondering if it could have been closed for this reason because there were two answers that were very nearly (if not completely) equal in correctness.

I doubt there would be any other proverb that fits this template, so it's probably safe to say there are only these two answers that could fit. Does this make the puzzle too broad, or would a puzzle need more possible answers to be closed for this reason?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would not say that makes the puzzle *too broad*.  On a site like StackOverflow, there could easily be two different and equally *good* and valid answers to a given question, so I don't see why it should be any different here.

The problem with *too broad* is when the problem is either insufficiently defined, or too open-ended to be able to definitively say whether a given answer "fits" well.

In the case you refer to, neither of those criteria apply; there are simply two good answers to the puzzle.